# Get input name from Rails form builder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I get a string with form input name?

```
<%= form_with model: @post do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <!-- Will produce HTML <input type="text" id="post_name" name="post[name]" value="" /> -->
<% end %>
```

The question is how can I get the name of input name without generating it? Is this example it should be a string "post[name]"

Answer (score 4):

When you are within a `form_with model: @post` block you could build the `"post[name]"` string like this:

```
"#{dom_class(f.object)}[name]"
```

See the docs of [`dom_class`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.3/classes/ActionView/RecordIdentifier.html#method-i-dom_class)

Comment: And what if I need to get name inside fields_for scope? I there any general-purpose method? Without any hardcoding

Comment: The general-purpose method is to call `dom_class(f.object)` where `f` is the block parameter from the `form` block _or_ the `fields_for` block.

Answer (score 1):

What you could be looking for is the `object_name` method

`f.object_name` should return `"post"`

It will work as well for multiple nested `fields_for`

```
<%= form_with model: @team do |team| %>
  <%= team.fields_for :players do |player| %>
  <%# for 1st player: player.object_name #=> "team[players_attributes][0]" %>
<% end %>
```

What ever you case is, you still have to concatenate your field name between brackets `"[field_name]"`, and so you can easily construct the right name for your input's field